# php substring Issue

Tags: php, substring

I have the following string:

```
$str = "ABACADAF";
```

I am using the following code:

```
$first2 = substr($str, 0, 2);
```

I want to get the following output:

```
output => `AB,AC,AD,AF`
```

(Every two characters separated by comma)

But the result I'm getting is not correct.

I checked the php manual but that is not helping, is there some foreach loop to iterate through all the string characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that you can use to output from a foreach. We're finding two capital letter matches and putting them into an array, then we implode that `array()` to make a string.

```
<?php
    function splitter($string){
        preg_match_all('/[A-Z]{2}/', $string, $matches);
        $newstring = implode(',',$matches[0]);
        return $newstring;
    }


    $strings = array("ABACADAF","ACABAFAC","AAABAFAD","ACACADAF");
    foreach($strings as $string){
        echo splitter($string)."\n";    
    }
?>
```

**Output**

```
AB,AC,AD,AF
AC,AB,AF,AC
AA,AB,AF,AD
AC,AC,AD,AF
```

If you're running a lot of them (millions of lines) you can use this function instead. It's much quicker.

```
function splitter($string){
    $newstring = substr(chunk_split($string, 2, ','), 0, -1);
    return $newstring;
}
```

Comment: Yet again :p Why not use that regex I've provided, next - that could be done by one regex (see my answer)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Even though it looks more elegant code-wise your `preg_replace` suggestion is actually slower than the `preg_match` function and the non-preg functions (of course). So it's cool, but a little more complicated in terms of processing.

Answer (score 4):

Not tested, but should be something along these lines:

```
<?php

$string = "ABACADAF";
$split = str_split($string, 2);
$implode = implode(",", $split);

echo $implode;

?>
```

Comment: you code seems net, but it is not working with me here foreach ($ro as $key=>$value) { 
           $str = $value['ro_code']; 
           $split = str_split($str, 2);
           $implode = implode(",", $split);

           echo $implode;
        }  Not working

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function. You can do like this:

```
$sResult = join(',', str_split($sData, 2));
```

Alternatively, you can do it via regex:

```
$sResult = preg_replace('/(..)(?!$)/', '$1,', $sData);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why people are upvoting this one because while it does show one of the keys to what the OP was kind of looking for, it doesn't explain anything. It's like a replacement for Google.

Comment: That is because - first of - an answer was the first (so Tom's answer expected to be a comment with an issue about `join`), and - second - this leaves a way for OP to _think_ and try it for himself. I beleive that's more SO style.

Comment: Your answer outputs this `A,B,A,C,A,D,A,F` You should test your code.

Comment: Anyway, I've added another solution to make an answer better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this or recursively as well.

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i< strlen($str); $i=$i+3)
{
    $str = substr($str,i,2).",".substr($str,3);
}
echo $str;
?>
```

I personally prefer the recursive implementation:

```
<?php

    function add_comma($str)
    {
        return substr($str, 0, 2,).','.add_comma(subtr($str,3));
    }
    echo add_comma($str);

?>
```

Comment: Getting all Rube Goldberg on us eh?

Comment: That's where the recursion comes in... Although the line length is still the same... :/

Answer (score 0):

While this is doable with a `for` loop, it is cleaner (and maybe faster), and more strait-forward in TomUnite's answer.

But since you asked...
With a for loop you could do it like this:

```
$withCommas = substr($string, 0, 2);

for($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i += 2){
    $withCommas+= "," . substr($string, $i, $i+2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution and Same output of your problem:
I personally tested it :

```
<?php
$str     =  "ABACADAF";
$first   =  substr($str, 0, 2);
$second  =  substr($str, 2, 2);
$third   =  substr($str, 4, 2);
$fourth  =  substr($str, 6, 2);

echo $output  =  $first.",".$second.",".$third.",".$fourth;     

?>
```

Comment: What happens when the user changes $str to be shorter or longer? The idea behind programming is to abstract your functions for broader usage. It is not good programming to limit any function to something so case specific as this.

Comment: I agree with you. But he defined his string statically, so i showed him the simplest way to perform this solution. And it will work for him. But on the other side your point is valid. A function will be way useful for different length of strings.